# Angularjs Adding two numbers

Tags: angularjs

Hi I want to add two field and put in another field

```
<input type="text" ng-model="pfi.value1">
<input type="text" ng-model="pfi.value2">
<input type="text" ng-model="pfi.sum" >
```

its working fine in label

```
<label>{{ pfi.value1 + pfi.value2}}</label>
```

but how to do same thing in text field

Comment: Does the same thing not work? Show what's not working

Comment: how to this in form field i tried <input type="text" ng-model="pfi.sum" ng-value="pfi.value1 + pfi.value2" >

Answer (score 2):

You should set `pfi.sum = pfi.value1 + pfi.value2;` inside your controller.  I'm not positive what the two-way binding would do if you then edited the text field attached to `pfi.sum`, but I suspect it wouldn't be good.  However, for display purposes, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the template

```
<input type="number" ng-model="pfi.value1">
<input type="number" ng-model="pfi.value2">
<input type="number" ng-model="pfi.sum" >

<p>{{ pfi.sum = pfi.value1 + pfi.value2}}</p>
```

The `$interpolation` service evaluates the exoression on each change to the inputs and updates the sum.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv2x7b3f/).

Answer (score 0):

you should do it on the controller
`pfi.sum = pfi.value1 + pfi.value2`
also,you need to add the controller to your html file.

Comment: yes i tried $scope.pfi.sum = $scope.pfi.value1 + $scope.pfi.value2 TypeError: Cannot read property 'value1 ' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

you should do that operation in your controller,
assuming you are using pfi for controllerAs attribute?

```
x.controller('xctrl', function() {
    var pfi = this;
    pfi.sum = pfi.value1 + pfi.value2;
});
```